# selecting an individual object that is identified as a class

Tags: jquery

I have an unknown number of "options" or swatches that are in the form of square shaped divs. Because the number of options are always unknown I can't assign them an ID.  I'm trying to make it so that when an option is clicked - it scales up.  It works using the following jq:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".option").on("click",function () {
        $(this).width("500px");
        $(this).height("500px");
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FFB2B2");
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FFB2B2");
    });

    $(".option").click(function () {
        $(this).off("click");
    });

});
```

However, every ".option" class scales and there could be 100's of them.  Does anybody no a work around?

Comment: With _individual object_ do you mean one or all that has the class `.option`?

Comment: they all have the class "option". I was trying to note that assigning an ID wouldn't work for this situation.  Hope that clears things up!!

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet that reproduce the issues

Comment: Thats pretty much it right there. There is a back end developer generating the HTML.  I think the "this" statement in is seemingly working on my "individual class" issue.  Now the issue is I can't seem to "reset" the option div back to its original size.  That might be a discussion for another thread....

Answer (score 1):

You've attached your click event to the `document` instead of the specific option element. Try attaching it to the `option` class:

```
$('.option').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).toggle({ effect: 'scale', percent: 300 });
});
```

Put this code in you document loading function.

Comment: Bad miss for me, I wish I noticed that. I fixed that but still not working unfortunately.  Everything I've read suggest this "off" should removed everything that "on" did if I'm understanding it correctly....